# Unable to create NVARCHAR2 > 2000

Tags: oracle, maxlength

in Oracle 18c I am not able to create table with column NVARCHAR2 with length >2000:

Error report -
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype
00910. 00000 -  "specified length too long for its datatype"
*Cause:    for datatypes CHAR and RAW, the length specified was > 2000;
otherwise, the length specified was > 4000.
*Action:   use a shorter length or switch to a datatype permitting a
longer length such as a VARCHAR2, LONG CHAR, or LONG RAW

Which is strange, because MAX_STRING_SIZE is STANDARD, so I should be able to store up to 4000.

What should be changed in DB setting to allow it?

Comment: Just asking: are you **sure** you chose ˛`NVARCHAR2`? Because, `NCHAR`'s upper limit is 2000 ...

Comment: Yes, I am sure. But as I just edited, the number of bytes can be up to two times size for AL16UTF16 encoding. And we use that encoding.

Answer (score 0):

With `MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD` the limit for `VARCHAR2`, `NVARCHAR2`, and `RAW` types in Oracle SQL is 4000 **bytes**.

When you specify `VARCHAR2(size)` the size is interpreted as a byte length by default. Therefore you can specify up to `VARCHAR2(4000)`.

When you specify `NVARCHAR2(size)` the size is interpreted as **character** length. The relevant character set is the *national character set*, which is AL16UTF16 by default. And for AL16UTF16 the multiplier to convert character length to byte length is 2. Therefore, you can specify up to `NVARCHAR2(2000)` because this converts to 4000 bytes.

Setting `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED` increases the capacity of `NVARCHAR` to 32767 **bytes** which means you could specify up to `NVARCHAR2(16383)`.
Note that changing `MAX_STRING_SIZE` in an existing database is more complicated than simply setting a parameter because metadata update is required for some database objects to account for the increased `VARCHAR2`, `NVARCHAR2`, and `RAW` capacity. [The process is explained in the Oracle Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html#GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C).

Note that Oracle's Autonomous Database Cloud Service on Shared Infrastructure (ADB-S) is setup with `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED` by default!

If you are interested in more details, there are some nuances:

- Are you sure you need to use `NVARCHAR2` at all? Typically if you choose a *database character set* that supports Unicode, such as AL32UTF8, then you can avoid `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, and `NCLOB` data types.
- It is possible to specify VARCHAR2 type with character length semantics, by using optional CHAR keyword like `VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)` or by setting `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter in the session to CHAR.
- Strictly speaking, for `NVARCHAR2(size)` size is not characters but *code points* in the national character set. Some characters use two code points in AL16UTF16.
- The national character set is AL16UTF16 by default, but could also be UTF8. The [Oracle documentation for NVARCAHR2 type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-CC15FC97-BE94-4FA4-994A-6DDF7F1A9904) explains the NVARCHAR2 limits for the different combinations of `MAX_STRING_SIZE` and national character set:

> The minimum value of size is 1. The maximum value is:
>
> 16383 if MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED and the national character set is AL16UTF16
>
> 32767 if MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED and the national character set is UTF8
>
> 2000 if MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD and the national character set is AL16UTF16
>
> 4000 if MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD and the national character set is UTF8